# If the point is defined, can we still calculate a limit?

Tags: calculus, limits

Say we have a really simple function, $$\mathtt f(x) = x - 1$$

And now someone asks, what's the limit of f(x) as x approaches zero from below?

$$\lim\limits_{x \to 0-}f(x)$$

Would the answer be -1? Or is there not an answer at all, because the point is defined?

Comment: Yes, it'd be zero. You can simply use direct substitution to affirm this.

Comment: Limit existence has "nothing" to do with the domain definition (limits only exist in $cl(A)$, but I don't think that is closely related to your question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Limits tell the value of the quantity when the input is nearly some value.  In this case when $x$ is close to $0$ but a little less, the value of your function is close to $-1$.  And the closer the value of $x$ is to $0$, the closer the function value is to $-1$.  The value of the function right at $0$ is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the function $g(x)=\lfloor x\rfloor$, where $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is the least integer *less than or equal to* $x$; for instance
$$
\lfloor 0\rfloor=0,
\quad
\lfloor 1/2\rfloor=0,
\quad
\lfloor -1/2\rfloor=-1,
$$
More generally, for $-1<x<0$, you have
$$
\lfloor x\rfloor=-1
$$
so
$$
\lim_{x\to0^-}g(x)=-1
$$
On the other hand, $g(0)=0$.

So, in general, you *can't* just substitute the value $g(0)$ in order to find the limit. This is certainly possible, however, if the function is [*continuous*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function) at $0$ (or, more generally, at the point where you're computing the limit). Your function $f(x)=x-1$ is indeed continuous at all points, in particular at $0$, so
$$
\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=\lim_{x\to0^-}f(x)=\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)=f(0)=-1
$$